# How do you see the cpu temperature in htop command? Does this work for WSL?

Tags: cpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, temperature, htop

Is there a way to see the CPU temperature in [htop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/htop.1.html). I am using windows10 wsl, so I'm not sure if WSL1 has access to CPU temperature reading.

Comment: I am not familiar with WSL, but what about the `sensors` command?

Comment: its WSL1 @K7AAY

Comment: The Linux kernel tools for interfacing with hardware don't currently work in WSL, since WSL does not use a Linux kernel. Since Windows is the OS in control of the hardware, you will have best luck using Windows tools to control and monitor that hardware. Obviously, Linux hardware tools work very well when you boot into Linux.

Comment: it looks like the new WSL 2 has a linux kernal. @user535733

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install seems quite clear that WSL is *virtualized*. The virtualized kernel, Linux (WSL2) or not (WSL1), has no access to the real hardware. It can only see the virtual platform that Windows provides. Whether or not Windows provides an API to simulate hardware access seems more like a Windows support question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A review of the man page for [htop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/htop.1.html) does not show it has that ability. It is a process viewer, not designed to read sensors.

Comment: In its current state, this answer was true for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but on on 22.04 LTS htop is built with sensors support: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/htop.1.html (CTRL+F libsensors)

Answer (score 6):

htop provides temperature data via libsensors. This feature is a build-time option.
https://github.com/htop-dev/htop#linux

Comment: Suprised to learn this. Installed lm-sensors and libsensors-dev through apt, then went into the htop setup menu (press F2) > Display options > also show CPU temperature. Seems the htop from apt is already compiled with this